# Querying elasticsearch with OR and wildcards

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

I'm trying to do a simple query to my elasticsearch _type and match multiple fields with wildcards, my first attempt was like this:

```
POST my_index/my_type/_search
{
  "sort" : { "date_field" : {"order" : "desc"}},
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "or" : [
          {
              "term" : { "field1" : "4848" }
          },
          {
              "term" : { "field2" : "6867" }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This example will successfully match every record when field1 OR field2 are exactly equal to 4848 and 6867 respectively.

What I'm trying to do is to match on field1 any text that contains 4848 and field2 that contains 6867 but I'm not really sure how to do it.

I appreciate any help I can get :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your problem has mostly to do with [analysis](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html). The appropriate solution depends on the structure of your data and what you want to match. I'll provide a couple of examples.

First, let's assume that your data is such that we can get what we want just using the [standard analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html). This analyzer will tokenize text fields on whitespace, punctuation and symbols. So the text `"1234-5678-90"` will be broken into the terms `"1234"`, `"5678"`, and `"90"`, so a `"term"` query or filter for any of those terms will match that document. More concretely:

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
   },
   "mappings": {
       "doc": {
           "properties": {
               "field1":{
                   "type": "string",
                   "analyzer": "standard"
               },
               "field2":{
                   "type": "string",
                   "analyzer": "standard"
               }
           }
       }
   }
}

POST /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":1}}
{"field1": "1212-2323-4848","field2": "1234-5678-90"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":2}}
{"field1": "0000-0000-0000","field2": "0987-6543-21"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":3}}
{"field1": "1111-2222-3333","field2": "6867-4545-90"}

POST test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "or": [
               {
                  "term": { "field1": "4848" }
               },
               {
                  "term": { "field2": "6867" }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "field1": "1212-2323-4848",
               "field2": "1234-5678-90"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "field1": "1111-2222-3333",
               "field2": "6867-4545-90"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

(Explicitly writing `"analyzer": "standard"` is redundant since that is the default analyzer used if you do not specify one; I just wanted to make it obvious.)

On the other hand, if the text is embedded in such a way that the standard analysis doesn't provide what you want, say something like `"121223234848"` and you want to match on `"4848"`, you will have to do something little more sophisticated, using [ngrams](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html#analysis-ngram-tokenizer). Here is an example of that (notice the difference in the data):

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "nGram_filter": {
               "type": "nGram",
               "min_gram": 2,
               "max_gram": 20,
               "token_chars": [
                  "letter",
                  "digit",
                  "punctuation",
                  "symbol"
               ]
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "nGram_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "nGram_filter"
               ]
            },
            "whitespace_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
          "properties": {
               "field1":{
                   "type": "string",
                   "index_analyzer": "nGram_analyzer", 
                   "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
               },
               "field2":{
                   "type": "string",
                   "index_analyzer": "nGram_analyzer", 
                   "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
               }
           }
      }
   }
}

POST /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":1}}
{"field1": "121223234848","field2": "1234567890"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":2}}
{"field1": "000000000000","field2": "0987654321"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":3}}
{"field1": "111122223333","field2": "6867454590"}


POST test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "or": [
               {
                  "term": { "field1": "4848" }
               },
               {
                  "term": { "field2": "6867" }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 8,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "field1": "121223234848",
               "field2": "1234567890"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "field1": "111122223333",
               "field2": "6867454590"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

There is a lot going on here, so I won't attempt to explain it in this post. If you want more explanation I would encourage you to read this blog post: http://blog.qbox.io/multi-field-partial-word-autocomplete-in-elasticsearch-using-ngrams. Hope you'll forgive the shameless plug. ;)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Sloan, I want to take a few minutes to thank you properly, people like you not only solve other people problems (like mine), but you teach and point into the right direction (learning more). I will read and study everything you said here. Thank you a lot